# Is there a way to prevent a search term getting converted to a tag automatically?

Tags: support

Let's say I want to find all questions that are not tagged 'foo', but include the word 'foo' (maybe *should* be tagged 'foo'). I tried to search for `-[foo] foo`, but that didn't work as it got converted to `-[foo] [foo]`. Is there another trick?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow the ability to search for words which are the names of tags without being forced to only search for posts with those tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274235/allow-the-ability-to-search-for-words-which-are-the-names-of-tags-without-being)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put it in quotes.

> "javascript"

Additionally for terms in titles as well

> +javascript

Answer (score 4):

I think if you put it in quotes it will check for  the string, not the tag.

For a test, try searching for `"support"` on Meta.