# Allow the ability to search for words which are the names of tags without being forced to only search for posts with those tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

For instance, sometimes I want to search for all posts which mention `security`, however when I put that into the search it immediately puts these `[]` around it and searches for all posts with that tag instead. Now in some cases this may be useful, however not all those who put the word `security` into their post have also put the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag, so then it becomes impossible to search for those posts without that tag, but with that word in them.

And of course I was just using `security` as an example, I find this incredibly annoying when searching for any word which is also the name of a tag when I am not looking for all the posts that have that tag, but rather just that word.

So I suggest that there should either be an override such as putting, say `---` before and after the word like this in the search `---security---` so that it doesn't treat it as a tag, or if one does not put the word in `[]` in the search, for it to perhaps suggest those tags, or tell you that in order to search for tags you have to put the `[]` around each one, but not to actually automatically do it for you and thus prevent you from just searching for the word normally, rather than as a tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to override it. You can simply surround the word with quotation marks. So `"security"` would search for the word security and not get converted to a tag.

Also of note, the system only auto-converts your text to a tag if that is the only word in your search and it matches one of the top 60 tags on the site.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I can't reproduce that with "security" in the [ubuntu.se] search. It simply is not popular enough. It converts e.g. "wireless" instead though, as expected. Thanks for this clarification!

Comment: Ok, well, then it would be nice if this was documented somewhere.