# Inconsistent search behaviour with words equaling tag names

Tags: support, search

I just typed *food* into the search box at [opendata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) and this gives me search results containing the *word* food. The search query is `https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=food`.
[food] [is a tag at opendata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food).

Same when searching for *sleep* at [Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/): the query is `https://productivity.stackexchange.com/search?q=sleep`.

But I recently noticed<sup>*</sup> at other SE sites that if you enter a word that is also a tag name, this initiates a search for the tags:

Search for 'delphi' at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) performs `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi`
Search for 'professionalism' at [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) performs `https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism`

Why this inconsistent behavior?
Or is this 'consistent' one way for beta sites and the other way for non-beta?

<sup>* At the time I considered this unwanted behaviour—if I want a tag, I'll search for [tag]—but that is another issue, partially adressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274235/allow-the-ability-to-search-for-words-which-are-the-names-of-tags-without-being).</sup>